# How to get update from mercurial branch in teamcity

Tags: mercurial, repository, branch, teamcity

I want to use a particular branch in order to deploy. I am using teamcity to set up a VCS Settings. 
My current repository directory structure is as follows:-

```
My default dir:- http://hg.test.co.uk/mainbranch
branches - ver-11.6
     - ver-11.5
```

Now in VCS Settings teamcity I am setting it as follows:-

```
Pull changes from: https://hg.test.co.uk/mainbranch
default branch : 
Branch Specification: +:/branches/ver-11.6
```

When I run it from teramcity it always update from default. I want it to update from branch  ver11.6. Please guide what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to type `/branches/`.  Use raw branch name.  Correct branch specification is  `+:ver-11.6` for branch `ver-11.6`.